# Getting error response after sending JSONObject to post request using retrofit2 android

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit2

**Request Sent :-**

```
@POST("config")

fun postApi(@Body jsonBody: JSONObject): Call<ResponseBody>
```

**I am getting response body like below :-**

```
{"Response":{"Error":[{"message":"Error parsing JSON: unexpected token: bracket. (15360)\nUnable to infer Temp-Table or dataset schema from JSON Data. (15374)"}]}}
```

**Callback Method :-**

```
call?.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {

      override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.e("BASE_URL isSuccess  : ", response.isSuccessful.toString())
                        Log.e("BASE_URL response : ", response.body()!!.string())

                    } else {
                        Log.e("failed", response.isSuccessful.toString())
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("onFailure", t.printStackTrace().toString())
                }
            })
```

Comment: have you check this api in your postman?

Comment: Yes..in postman its working fine.

Comment: You guys can refer this link:- https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/44764/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two ways to solve this problem.

1. Create POJO (data class in Kotlin) class, prepare data, and pass the object to the function. You need to change the function like this

   ```java
   @POST("config")
   fun postApi(@Body jsonBody: YourPojoClass): Call<ResponseBody>
                         //------^^^^^^------ notice the data type here.
   ```
2. Use `JsonObject` from `com.google.gson` package instead of using `JSONObject` from `org.json` package. It works perfectly with `@Body` annotation. So, change the method parameter like below.

   ```java
   @POST("config")
   fun postApi(@Body jsonBody: JsonObject): Call<ResponseBody>
                         //------^^^^^^------ notice the data type here.
   ```

Please note that the class name is `JsonObject` not `JSONObject`. The 2nd method is easy as you don't have to create a new POJO class.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was sending JSONObject in request which is converting to string in retrofit than I changed my request to JsonObject than its working fine.  I fixed the problem by your 2nd solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do not send JSONObject directly, convert your JSONObject to RequestBody. So first change `postApi`'s prototype:

```
@POST("config")
fun postApi(@Body jsonBody: RequestBody): Call<ResponseBody>
```

From the caller site:

```
postApi(yourJsonObject.toRequestBody())
```

Here is the method to convert json object to request body:

```
fun JSONObject.toRequestBody():RequestBody{
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), this.toString())
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I fixed the problem by changing my request to JsonObject instead of JSONObject.